# Magento: how to log messages in custom module install script?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, log, install-script

I would like to know **how to log messages in custom module install script.**

File path:

```
app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/sql/modulename_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.1.php
```

The script is running fine. I'm able to debug the file and see the SQL error, moreover, *core_resource* table is updated properly but the message under the catch block is not logged at:

```
var/log/modulename_setup.log
```

My script:

```
<?php

try {
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();
    $installer->run("
       CREATE TABL 'dummy_table' (
        'id' int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
         PRIMARY KEY ('id')
       ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    ");
    $installer->endSetup();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    Mage::log('Something went wrong.', null, 'modulename_setup.log');
}

?>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I faced the problem before, the only way I managed to get it working was by forcing the log by setting the 4th parameter of `Mage::log` to true so in your case I suggest you use the following code

```
Mage::log('Something went wrong.', null, 'modulename_setup.log', true);
```

Comment: @brunof feel free to mark your question as answered so it will benefit for others

Comment: I've tried but I'm not able because my reputation is under 15 points. =(

Comment: @brunof you don't need to upvote to mark your question as answered you should be able to click the tick mark next to my answer can't you?